# Are exposed cables along the ceiling in a finished garage code-compliant?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, nec

Bought a house a year ago, previous owner had an electrician re-wire a lot of the house when they did a bunch of remodeling about 4 years ago. They ran all the cables on the wood center beam in the garage. Is this allowed and compliant with NEC? I am finishing my basement and ran all my cables with the same cables, I am just wondering if the inspector will cite this for not being in conduit?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It may not be pretty, and you can cover it if you'd like (I'd suggest an easily removable cover), but it strikes me as being 100% code compliant and installed in a very neat, tidy and "workmanlike manner". My only question would be how they exit the panel to get up to the ceiling, that _might_ require a covering. NOTE: I am _not_ an electrician, but I've learned a fair bit...

Comment: What's going on with the extension cords in the first photo?

Comment: See also [Can I run wire along a finished wall/ceiling in a basement?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/152594/can-i-run-wire-along-a-finished-wall-ceiling-in-a-basement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an unfinished basement that is fine.

However for a finished room exposed cable is a no.

You will need to encase that run of cables into something. This can be as simple as surrounding it with some plywood. Or you can frame a small enclosure around it and use drywall. As there are no electrical connections in that run there doesn't need to be an access panel but I would suggest having some anyway in case you want to pull another cable through.

You mentioned that you ran a wire along that bundle and I can see a non-romex cable with plug-in connections, depending on what it is, its rating, and its purpose you cannot have that encased as well.

Comment: An easy way to protect it is plastic cable guard.  You would just screw a piece over top, and done.   Here is [an example](https://www.grainger.com/category/electrical/wire-cable-management/surface-raceways-cable-concealers/outdoor-cable-guards), this one is cheap, U-shaped, and kinda ugly but there are all sorts.

Comment: Is it a "no" aesthetically or is there a code requirement that this be covered? AFAIK, cable more than 84" (I think) above ground level doesn't need to be protected from impact damage. Unless the OP has _very_ low garage ceilings, this seems to meet code requirements...

Comment: @FreeMan The NEC does not specify 84", it is more broad prohibiting NM where "exposed to physical damage". I have worked in jurisdictions that have ammended the code to require covering all low voltage and line voltage to be covered below 84", but the 84" rule doesn't limit the inspectors from judging some areas above 84" still being exposed to physical damage.

Comment: Define "finished". Is a garage with untaped drywall finished? Is a garage with OSB wall and ceiling sheathing finished? That sounds like a fuzzy term. I'd be curious how code actually addresses it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @NoSparksPlease. Presuming that _this much_ electrical work was permitted (OP stated "had an electrician..."), one would also presume that the work was inspected and the local inspector was quite satisfied with the efforts made.

Comment: I appreciate all the answers, based on all your responses I will plan to box out the electrical by essentially framing out around it with additional 1x4 boards. Hopefully that pleases the inspector. The "extension cord" is just a wire that runs between two LED lights.